# Nested factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I am trying to define factories for my tests like this:

```
factory :content do
  id
  name
  after(:create) do |content|
    create(:title, :title_id => content.id)
  end
end

# --------------

factory :title do
  title_id
  title_name
  after(:create) do |title|
    create(:some_other_model, :this_id => title.title_id)
  end
end`
```

So basically, I want to set up lets say 5 tables with some data for my test, which needs to be done in a particular order so that the next record inserted can have an id of the previous one. This is possible with the factories I have defined above with just one call like this: `FactoryGirl.create(:content)` as it is internally making calls as defined in the factories

Now, lets say I want to do the same thing but set a particular value for an attribute deeper in the stack(e.g. `:some_other_model.name => 'Name')`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant, but I have followed this pattern several times in my factories:

```
factory :foobar do
  ignore do
    goobar_color nil
  end

  after(:create) do |foobar, evaluator|
    create(:goobar, :foobar => foobar, :goobar_color => evaluator.goobar_color)
  end
end
```

Then when you create a foobar, you can specify the color of the related goobar:

```
create(:foobar, :goobar_color => "red")
```

You should be able to extend this deeper if you want to (i.e. have the goobar factory create a hoobar object whose attributes can be set by the foobar factory).